# Where do I put CSS in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

Where do I put CSS or JS files in the Laravel framework?

To be more specific, is there a difference between putting CSS in `/public` and putting it in `/resources/css`? Where should I put my CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put css files in `/resources/css` then you have to run
`npm run dev` or `npm run production` so that the webpack can process them and put them in `public/css` that is reccomended.

You can put them directy in `public/css`. Then they will be available in your app